# Designer-editing DataSource property of a DataGridView within a UserControl

Tags: c#, user-controls, datagridview, datasource, uitypeeditor

I have a custom UserControl that contains several child controls, amongst which is a DataGridView. I don't want to EnableDesignMode for any of the child controls, but instead have exposed and serialized their properties as needed. I'm stuck on DataGridView's DataSource property.

Do I need to make a custom UITypeEditor and use reflection to find all the BindingSource objects on the parent form for selection, or can I somehow invoke the built-in editor of this type? What type is the editor invoked when changing DataGridView's DataSource?

EDIT: Actually, the suggestion from Oliver did not quite work out. I did get the list of bindable objects in the property grid when I select my UserControl and after I chose a binding source, columns of bound dataset appeared on the grid, but columns of datagridview are not serialized to designer.cs after editing the Columns collection. However, if I build a custom ParentControlDesigner and EnableDesignMode for this datagridview, I can set the binding via it's DesignerVerb, and then the Columns collection is serialized after editing.

I exposed datagridview's Columns and DataSource properties in this way

```
[Editor(typeof(CollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
[Category("Grid")]
//[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public DataGridViewColumnCollection Columns
{
    get { return dgvListaBaza.Columns; }
}

[AttributeProvider(typeof(IListSource))]
[Browsable(true)]
[Category("Grid")]
public object DataSource
{
    get { return dgvList.DataSource; }
    set { dgvList.DataSource = value; }
}
```

What is the difference between the way DataSource is set when I click on the control's native designerverb and the one through exposed property? Both show the columns of the bindingSource in the grid after i choose a binding, but Columns don't get serialized in the latter case, as if there is something else I need to set when setting the DataSource.

Also, DesignerSerializationVisibility attribute on the exposed Columns makes no difference, and the column Names in the CollectionEditor are different depending on the way I set the DataSource (If it's set through native designerverb, then they are named SomeColumnDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, and if it's set through the property, then the Name property of each column is empty).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [DataSource for User Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478278/datasource-for-user-control).

Comment: [AttributeProvider(typeof(IListSource))] did the trick! Thanks.